# FIREBASE APP Failed to deploy, HTTP Error: 500, Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: http, firebase, deployment

I have a firebase app that when I go to deploy it [firebase deploy] it returns this error.

HTTP Error: 500, Request contains an invalid argument.

Terminal output
[image]

The debug log says:

```
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] Command:      /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy
[debug] CLI Version:  3.1.0
[debug] Platform:     darwin
[debug] Node Version: v4.6.1
[debug] Time:         Tue Nov 08 2016 19:28:28 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
[debug] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/chat-4d6fb 
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/chat-4d6fb/tokens 
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'chat-4d6fb'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying database, storage, hosting
[info] ✔  database: rules ready to deploy.
[info] i  storage: checking rules for compilation errors...
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/chat-4d6fb:test
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  storage: rules file compiled successfully
[info] i  hosting: preparing ./ directory for upload...
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/chat-4d6fb/uploads/-KW5U6Mb3XEOtWn_Kfam?fileCount=14&message= 
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  hosting: ./ folder uploaded successfully
[info] ✔  hosting: 14 files uploaded successfully
[info] i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/projects/chat-4d6fb/releases
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 500
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY
[error] 
[error] Error: HTTP Error: 500, Request contains an invalid argument.
[debug] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
      "message": "Request contains an invalid argument."
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument."
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "server": "nginx",
      "date": "Wed, 09 Nov 2016 00:28:39 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "content-length": "84",
      "connection": "close",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "deploy.firebase.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "deploy.firebase.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/v1/projects/chat-4d6fb/releases",
        "path": "/v1/projects/chat-4d6fb/releases",
        "href": "https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/projects/chat-4d6fb/releases"
      },
      "method": "POST"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or have any advice that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

How about logging in again using `firebase login:ci`?
It will generate a new token. And you can deploy using `firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"`